# Authenticate to Stack Exchange using GitHub

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login, authentication, github

I've seen sign in methods using [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) as an authentication provider, for example [c9.io](https://c9.io/login): (AWS Cloud9)

> [image]

Is it possible to authenticate into Stack Exchange using this method? At the moment there's other methods such as OpenID, Google, Yahoo and Facebook, but it would be interesting to also have the GitHub authentication.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can log into any Stack Exchange site using the credentials from any Open ID provider.  Unfortunately, at this time, GitHub is not an Open ID provider, so you can't log in using those credentials.

Also, it's highly unlikely that SE would create a special login mechanism for GitHub accounts unless there was great incentive to do so; it would require resources (time, money) to fabricate a custom mechanism when one already exists for this specific purpose (Open ID).

If anything, I suggest that you urge GitHub to become an Open ID provider, rallying support around that initiative.  Once they are an Open ID provider, you'll be able to login to *any* Stack Exchange site with those credentials and link them to your account.

Comment: or, OAuth 2.0 which is nearly as convenient.

Comment: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

Comment: @Tracker1 It's still not OpenID, unfortunately.

Comment: @casperOne Neither Facebook is openID provider…

Comment: @skalee Very true, but that's a choice that the SE folk decided to make, presumably in order to reduce friction in logging into not just SO, but *all* of the Stack Exchange sites, many of which have nothing to do with coding.  In providing Facebook as a login provider, they reduce the friction for almost a billion people to access Stack Exchange sites.  That said, I'd still push this for Stack Overflow, as it makes perfect sense.  Also, the [OAuth token exchange] is simple enough to implement.  All that they have to do is ask for the `user:email` scope so that they can try to sync accounts.

Comment: I don't see how this answer gets so many upvotes and why this thread is marked as _answered_ and feels like [tag:status-declined]. [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/), the little sister of Stack Exchange for example, offers Github authentication by default, and that's _just a forum_. I don't see why a network with mainly technical and scientific Q&A sites should not offer Github authentication, as so many developers hang around on Github all day long and by any chance pop over to Stackoverflow to get help.

Comment: There are sites that uses GitHub authentication like Code Review and CodePen. So whay would it require resources to make this?

Comment: Now that StackOverflow want to remove support for OpenID, this answer will unfortunately no longer be relevant... :(

Comment: This new service use github connect: https://stackshare.io/

Answer (score 15):

The PR was finally approved and merged: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/11/announcing-support-for-github-authentication-in-stack-overflow/

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to set up a personal page, which utilizes "openid.delegate" to forward to the "openid.server". This is done in the HEAD section of that page by using "meta" and "link" tags.

For inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1223529

For testing use this: http://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx

Comment: Followup note: **this will not work** after July 25th, 2018, thanks to SO retiring their support for OpenID.

(Sadface; I was one of the 13K active OpenID users.)

Answer (score 7):

This is **definitely** possible...

I login to `SO.com`, etc. using my `openid` of `mralexgray.github.com`, *which is my* `gh-pages` URL.  I **forget** how I set this up... *at some point in the distant past*... but **I will** research it and update this answer.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to figure this out?

Comment: I guess @Pops that http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224525/168089 is the answer

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that they do support OAuth3 it looks like...